# Why do commands like cat immediately exit when run in background?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm making a custom shell in c, and I'm not entirely sure how processes running in the background works.

I thought I had a pretty good grip, but I'm not sure what happens to file descriptor 0, for example.

A command like 'cat', when passed without arguments expects input from stdin.

If you run cat in the background without arguments (e.g.: cat &), it will immediately terminate. Why does this actually happen, was cat's file descriptor 0 closed somehow?

I tried handling this by setting its file descriptor 0 to /dev/null, but then cat complains about having a bad file descriptor.

Any information about how the shell actually handles stdin to background processes would be much appreciated!

Update: Setting fd 0 to /dev/null works, but is that what the shell actually does? Does the shell set the file descriptor 0 of the background process to /dev/null? If so, what does the shell do if you move to to foreground,  does it set it back to 0? (by the way, I'm doing this for the first process in a pipe if there is more than one process)

Comment: How are you setting fd 0 to `/dev/null`? `cat </dev/null&` works as expected without complaint.

Comment: int fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
dup2(fd, 0);
close(fd);

Comment: nvm, the following works:

int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY, S_IRWXU);
dup2(fd, 0);
close(fd);

is that what the shell actually does though?

Comment: Whoops I was editing while you edited and your edit was removed, feel free to put it back in

Comment: "Setting fd 0 to /dev/null works, but is that what the shell actually does?" Yes, that's what it does in a shell **without** job control (eg. when the shell is running a script). The easiest way to check on Linux is with this: `sh -c 'ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 & echo'`

Comment: This question is off topic. Questions about the operation of the Linux operating system should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rob: I respectfully disagree. [unix.se] is primarily fir questions about using unix, not programming questions; its guidelines say "If your question is a programming question, requiring knowledge of programming languages other than unix shell scripting languages, ask on Stack Overflow." This question is basically a question about programming in C and fits here perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happens when I run `cat` in the background:

```
$ cat&
[1] 19322
$ 

[1]+  Stopped                 cat
$
```

Note that the `cat` process has not terminated. It's been suspended.

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
$ ps u 19322
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
rici     19322  0.0  0.0  11788   784 pts/4    T    01:48   0:00 cat
```

Backgrounded tasks cannot read from a terminal device. When they try to do that, they receive a SIGTTIN signal. The default action associated with that signal is to stop the task. But it hasn't been terminated; you can still resuscitate it by bringing it back to the foreground:

```
$ fg
cat
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

There is a detailed explanation in [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/), section 9.8.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. Do you have any suggestions on how this could be implemented in a custom shell?

Comment: @Ofek: APUE goes into a lot more detail. The book is highly recommended if you're planning on learning how to program in a Unix environment. Maybe it's even a text for your course :-)

Comment: this is actually beyond a course xD I'm coding this for fun, believe it or not. implementing up and down arrow support for history was a pain.

I was hoping to get some explanation without needing to purchase anything, and thanks for your explanation!

Currently my custom shell doesn't realize that cat received the SIGTTIN signal until I try moving it to the fg. When I try to resuscitate it using kill with SIGCONT, it is still stopped for some reason (waitid w/ WSTOPPED immediately exits).

Do you have an idea how to 1) know that a child received SIGTTIN, 2) successfully continue

Comment: @ofek: you can try [this online resource](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html) but APUE is a good investment. You can probably find a used copy.

Comment: @OfekGila you don't have to implement it in the shell. It's the *kernel* who is sending the `SIGTTIN` (and the `SIGHUP` on the tty being teared up, `SIGINT` on ^C, etc). All the shell has to do is to move processes between jobs (process group), and change the job which is the foreground one on the tty.

Comment: thanks for all your feedback! it really helped!

@mosvy: as rici showed above, the 'jobs' command correctly identifies that cat is Stopped. how does it know that cat is stopped rather than running in the background?

Comment: @ofek: if the parent does not ignore `SIGCHLD`, it will be signalled both when a child terminates and when a child is stopped (unless you ask for stop notifications to be suppressed). If you install the signal handler with `sigaction`, the `siginfo_t` argument to the signal handler will contain the information needed to know whether (and why) the child was stopped. (See the `si_status` member).

Comment: I think this is covered in the Gnu resource I linked to above. It's certainly in APUE and muchbof it can be gleaned by reading the manpage for `sigaction`. The section in Posix about signal handling is also useful.